# Encode a fileHandler to output unicode characters

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, filehandler

I'm using Java `FileHandler` in my application to write a log file. i need to get output in Unicode characters. so i have set encoding as `fileHandler.setEncoding("UTF-8");` in my application. but Unicode characters in output is still display as `?????`.

how could i solve this ?

Comment: Which tool do you use for displaying output file ?

Comment: @zim2001 Notepad++. also tried with Notepad

Comment: Could you provide revelant part of your code declaring and using the FileHandler ?

Comment: Where do the unicode characters come from, do you read them from a file or are they hard coded in the program? If the first, are you sure the file is being read correctly?

Comment: @Joni  unicode characters come from a XML File. I wrote my program for read xml file and add data into a database. file is reading correctly. because data are correct in database.